# what does `Count : Count` in `CommandList[Count:Count + len(Command)] == Command` do in python?

Tags: python

I don't know what 'Count : Count' does in my code. Below is the function that this is used in on line 4

I tried printing it but it gave me an error. CommandList is a string variable as well as Command.

```
def GetPositionOfCommand(CommandList, Command):
    Position = Count = 0
    while Count <= len(CommandList) - len(Command):
        if CommandList[Count:Count + len(Command)] == Command:
            return Position
        elif CommandList[Count] == ",":
            Position += 1
        Count += 1
    return Position

Position = GetPositionOfCommand(Items[IndexOfItem].Commands, "get")
```

Comment: This is a syntax for Python's list slicing. Refer [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) to understand more about it.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is not a duplicate. The OP is not quite confused by the slice, but rather by the incorrect grouping of items within the bracket. He or she thinks `Count:Count` is a separate expression. Therefore I answered the question.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Daulton. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is off, since `Count: Count` does nothing in the code you show. Rather, what acts is `Count:Count + len(Command)`. That would be better written as `Count: (Count+len(Command))`.

Both `CommandList` and `Command` are strings or lists or similar data types (I'll say strings hereafter), while `Count` is an integer. In particular, `Count` is an index into `CommandList`.

The expression `CommandList[Count:Count + len(Command)]` is [a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) of `CommandList`. In other words, that expression is a sub-string of the string `CommandList`. That sub-string begins at the index position held in `Count` and stops just before the index position `Count + len(Command)`. That sub-string has the same length that the string `Command` has.

Therefore the entire line

```
if CommandList[Count:Count + len(Command)] == Command:
```

checks if the sub-string pointed to by variable `Count` is equal to the string `Command`. If the sub-string and the string are equal, the next line executes, namely the `return` statement.

Is that clear? Read up more on Python's slices--the link I gave you is a good start. Slices are just one reason Python handles lists and strings so much better than most other languages. The code is written a little confusingly, so it looks like `Count:Count` is an expression in itself. The code should have used different spacing and perhaps parentheses to show that the inner expression is `Count + len(Command)` and the colon is used after that. Order of operations shows itself again!